# what is the use of cond and let reserve words in erlang?

Tags: erlang

what  is the use of "cond" and "let" reserved words in erlang, i saw them in reserved words list but never seen any use in erlang or any example of them in erlang, i also search on google but got nothing.

It seems to me that they are just reserved, just like "goto" and "const" in java but i may be wrong. so please explain those keywords with little examples as well.

```
-module(hello_world).

start() ->
    io:format("hello_world").
```

Comment: There have been some EEP recommendations about using a universalized `cond` expression to ease the "nested case" problem, and I'm not really sure why `let` was reserved other than its a verb and not unreasonable to keep off the market in a functional program -- lest `let` expressions become useful in some way later and that change break a bunch of code that was using `let` atom values. If I find a reference I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe they are reserved for the same reason `goto` is reserved in Java: in this paradigm the terms `cond` and `let` have rather specific meanings, and it would be confusing to have programmers use those atoms unquoted.

It also may be that, given the way scoping works with list comprehensions and the general desire to avoid nested `case` statements (and aversion to `if` in most cases) it may be useful to use `cond` or `let` in the future.

There are two EEPs that mention these: [EEP12](http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0012.html) and [EEP25](http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0025.html)

EEP12 mentione `let` as part of a larger discussion, citing Haskell `let`s.

EEP25 mentions that with a generalized `case` a previous recommendation for a generalized `cond` would be unnecessary -- but I don't know what recommendation this refers to (maybe a previous draft of the EEP).

In any case, reserving a word is easy to do up-front -- it is never a breaking change to reserve a word early, or to release it sometime later after you're *sure* you don't need it. Reserving a word that was previously unreserved, though, is a recipe for disaster. It is arguable worse to suddenly find that you really need a term like `let`, but can't use it because its already important in other programs people have -- and so you wind up having to make up some nonstandard term people can't remember and is confusing to newcomers to the language who are already familiar with the semantics of the basic paradigm.